# Can't connect properly an input range value to javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, range

I created (build on template) a simple js form. Everything is working with "radio" and "select" input, but i cant connect a "range" value  for sum it with everything else.

this how form and calculations works: (sorry for a lot of noobcode)

```js
function showVal(newVal){
  document.getElementById("valBox").innerHTML=newVal;
}

 function valNum(){

var valNum = document.getElementById("valBox")
 }

 var cake_prices = new Array();
 cake_prices["Round6"]=9;
 cake_prices["Round8"]=11;
 cake_prices["Round10"]=12;
 

 var filling_prices= new Array();
 filling_prices["Yearone"]=12;
 filling_prices["Yeartwo"]=60;
 filling_prices["Yearthree"]=120;


 var billing_prices= new Array();
 billing_prices["Billone"]=100;
 billing_prices["Billtwo"]=200;
 billing_prices["Billthree"]=300;
  billing_prices["Billfour"]=400;
billing_prices["Billfive"]=300;

  
  



function getCakeSizePrice()
{  
    var cakeSizePrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the cake the user Chooses name=selectedCake":
    var selectedCake = theForm.elements["selectedcake"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCake.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedCake.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedCake[i].checked)
        {
            //we set cakeSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
            //i.e. if the user choose the 8" cake we set it to 25
            //by using the cake_prices array
            //We get the selected Items value
            //For example cake_prices["Round8".value]"
            cakeSizePrice = cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the cakeSizePrice
    return cakeSizePrice;
}




     
function getBillingPrice()
{
    var cakeBillingPrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="filling"
     var selectedBilling = theForm.elements["billing"];
     
    //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
    //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
    cakeBillingPrice = billing_prices[selectedBilling.value];

    //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
    return cakeBillingPrice;
}





function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var cakePrice = (getCakeSizePrice() + getBillingPrice()) * valNum();
    var num = (cakePrice);
    var miPrice = parseInt (num - (num * .35));
    var miDiff = parseInt(cakePrice - miPrice);
    
    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total "+cakePrice;

    var divobj = document.getElementById('miPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total "+miPrice;


    var divobj = document.getElementById('miDiff');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total "+miDiff;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>Cake Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcalculations.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/cakeform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>

                <label >Select your province</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />SASKATCHEWAN</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round8" onclick="calculateTotal()" />MANITOBA</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedcake" value="Round10" onclick="calculateTotal()" />ALBERTA</label><br/>
                <br/>

                <br/>
                <br>

                
                </br>
                
                <label >BILL</label>
         
                <select id="billing" name='billing' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="Billone">100</option>
                <option value="Billtwo">200</option>
                <option value="Billthree">300</option>
                <option value="Billfour">400</option>
                <option value="Billfive">500</option>
               </select>
                <br/>

                <label >TOTAL WITH UTILITY</label>
                <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                


                <label >TOTAL WITH MI</label>
                <div id="miPrice"></div>

                <label >TOTAL SAVED</label>
                <div id="miDiff"></div>
                <br>

                <span id="valBox"></span>
<input type="range" min="5" max="10" step="1" 
   oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)">
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            
        
           
        </div>  
       </form>
 </div><!--End of wrap-->
</body>
</html>
```

everything is working without "range" input and valNum (do i created it correctly?) function. 
like if I'm doing:

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var cakePrice = (getCakeSizePrice() + getBillingPrice());
}
```

but when I'm adding newVal function chrome showing me total: NaN;

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var cakePrice = (getCakeSizePrice() + getBillingPrice()+newVal();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> everything is working without "range" input and valNum (do i created it correctly?) function....

```
var cakePrice = (getCakeSizePrice() + getBillingPrice()) * valNum();
```

-*`valNum()` func does not return any value.*

> but when I'm adding newVal function chrome showing me total: NaN;

```
var cakePrice = (getCakeSizePrice() + getBillingPrice()+newVal();
```

-*I don't see a `newVal()` func in the code. There is a newVal variable, but its scope is limited to the fucntion.*

---

Define a global variable and then define the function as below:

```
var valNum;
function valNum(){
    valNum = document.getElementById("valBox")
}
```

And make use of `valNum` as below :

```
var cakePrice = (parseFloat(getCakeSizePrice()) + parseFloat(getBillingPrice())) * parseFloat(valNum);
```

Comment: I added on top of .js file      `var valNum;
                     function valNum(){
                     valNum = document.getElementById("valBox")
                  }`     and aded valNum in - var cakePrice as you show, but sill it doesn't want to work, it shows: NaN as result(   also chrome console doesn't show me any errors.

Comment: Check for NaN using `isNan()` and use `parseFloat()` too. Check update answer.

Comment: Nothing changed, isNan showing true(        Maybe there is another way for show to js range input value? I don't want to bother you, sorry.

Comment: If `isNan()` shows true, the fault might be in the functions when you are getting values from `selectedCake[i].value`..etc. Though this is too late. Hope you found the solution.